# Backend for Phonegap-App - Is there one that fits my needs?

Tags: cordova, frameworks, backend

I'm currently working on an App based on Phonegap.

To this point, all dynamic data was received through simple ajax calls to PHP scripts on my server. Those scripts got the data from mySQL-tables and returned them in JSON-format. This already works fine. 
But now my customer requests more functionality and I'm looking for the right way to implement it.

The following is needed:

- User authentication (Email + PW)

  - the app will only be available for registered users
  - users will see personalized content
- User management (The Admin should be able to add/block/delete users)
- Very simple content management.

  - "Articles" can be created by the admin
  - "Articles" can be created by a simple script (currently: PHP)
  - There are articles which every user can see
  - There are articles which are directed at one specific user only
- *Optional: Analytics: Keeping track of the user's activities*

It would be good if I had an GUI for the admin to perform tasks like user and content management.

What are your thoughts?
Should I implement this from scratch on my own or can you think of a simple framework / BaaS for this tasks?
I looked into a few, but either they only offer functionality for one task (like Auth0), or they are much too complex for this project.

I'm really looking forward for your suggestions :)

Comment: Did you have a look at Symfony Framework? If you're not familiar with other web oriented framework it takes a bit of time to pick up (needed about a month to start being effective in my case). And you'll have to choose between keeping your pure SQL approach or switch to ORM (which uses SQL underneath, read about it if you don't know). You can have a look at the questions I've left on Stackoverflow those last 6 months to get an idea of the trouble you'll likely have to go thru if you take that path.

Comment: thank I will have a look at it. I'm also thinking about simply using WordPress with the REST-Plugin. I will keep you updated here.